# Enqueue function overwrites first entry on second iteration only

Tags: c, queue

I'm convinced that I'm missing a small detail here, but I can't seem to put my finger on it. If you can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it so much. I have a pretty straightforward enqueue function written in C:

```
int enqueue(char **queue, char *new_item) {

    if (queueLength >= MAX_ITEMS) {
        perror("Item count exceeds allowed range\n");
        return 1;
    }

    else {
        if (queueStart == -1) { // empty queue
            queueStart = 0;
            queueEnd = 0;
        }
        else {
            if (queueEnd == MAX_ITEMS - 1)
                queueEnd = 0;
            else queueEnd++;
        }

        // if queue[queueEnd] has not been initialized, allocate memory to initialize
        if (queue[queueEnd] == NULL) {

            if ((queue[queueEnd] = (char *)malloc(PATH_MAX * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
                perror("Could not allocate enough space for data");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        strcpy(queue[queueEnd], new_item);

        queueLength++;
    }

    // print queue
    int j = queueStart;
    while (j <= queueEnd) {
        printf("%s\n", queue[j]);
        j++;
    }
    printf("-----\n");

    return 0;
}
```

After invoking it once to add one item to my queue, my queue looks like this:

```
item1
```

After invoking it a second time, my queue looks like this:

```
item2
item2
```

After a third, fourth and fifth time:

```
item2
item2
item3
item4
item5
```

So the problem is isolated to that 2nd iteration. Any helpful observations, thoughts or comments are welcome!

Also, here is a snippet of the code that calls enqueue. inputFile is an open file stream.

```
char **queue;
char buff[PATH_MAX];
while (fgets(buff, PATH_MAX, inputFile) != NULL) {

    if (enqueue(queue, buff)) {
        printf("Failed to add client %s to queue", buff);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful to see the code that calls `unqueue` and prints that array.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the code I used to print out the contents of the queue.

Comment: Note: My print code was only there for debugging purposes and I realize that it doesn't work when the queue end wraps back around to the beginning.

Comment: It'll be best if you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `enqueue` function does not have the problem that you describe, which is why I agree with RSahu that you should put together an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. Found the answer: the issue was coming from improper memory allocation. The condition

```
queue[queueEnd] == NULL
```

was never actually being met, which was a misunderstanding of memory allocation on my part. To fix it, I removed the block of code allocating memory and instead just passed in a `char **` with all of its pointer elements already initialized.